# Event listener not working?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Sorry for so many questions, but I suck at javascript and want to get good at it. I'm trying to make a page change colors when you press a button as another proof of concept for me, but it's not working and I'm not entirely sure why...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button Id="BGchange">BUTTON!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
button.eventlistener(BGchange, BGcolor());
function BGcolor (){
var BG = BG2+1
var BG2 = BG
if(BG==0){
    document.body.style.background = white;
}
else
    if(BG==1){
        document.body.style.background = black;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

k, fixed a little, here's what I have now:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button Id="BGchange">BUTTON!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
BGchange.addEventListener("click", BGcolor);
var BG++
function BGcolor (){
if(BG==0){
backgroundcolor = "white";
}
else
    if(BG==1){
    backgroundcolor = "black";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `button.eventlistener(BGchange, BGcolor());` what does this line mean?

Comment: What is `button`? What is `eventlistener`? What is `BGchange`? But even without knowing that I can tell you that **calling** `BGcolor` at this moment is wrong. Have a look at these articles to learn about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: ... what is `BGchange` and why it's `BGcolor()`

Comment: That line means It senses BGchange, and starts the function BGcolor.

Comment: the bgchange is ONLY an ID

Comment: So, this line is pseudo-code, expressing what you want to do?

Comment: Felix, zerkms, @adeneo -- Enough with the rude comments. If you can't be helpful, don't comment. The OP admits to being new to JavaScript.

Comment: *"k, fixed a little, here's what I have now"* And, do you have a problem with that code or not? I really encourage you to [learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), so that you can find out yourself what is wrong with your code. Even if you cannot solve the issue, you are at least able to provide a better explanation of your problem.

Comment: There's already a working answer, did you look at that? Here's a working fiddle as well -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nvqCW/**

Comment: @Trevader24135 - Did you look at the working code I posted in my answer and the lengthy explanation I provided?  I would suggest that you start with that, make sure it's working as I've posted it and then modify it carefully from there.  Make one modification at a time from a working version so if something doesn't work, you know exactly what broke.  Also, you need to learn how to look at the browser error console or debug console which will show you where your script errors are and why your script doesn't run.  Google can explain to you how to find those.

Comment: Point John was making is that making jokes at the expense of others is rude. His comment was not rude at all @adeneo. Your response to him, on the other hand...

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to listen for an event click, then you need something like this:

```
 document.getElementById("BGchange").addEventListener("click", BGcolor);
```

Then, you need to fix some things in this function:

```
function BGcolor (){
    var BG = BG2+1
    var BG2 = BG
    if(BG==0){
        document.body.style.background = white;
    } else if (BG==1) {
        document.body.style.background = black;
    }
}
```

Because you are trying to reference `BG2` before it has been initialized so it is not clear what you want to be doing there.

In order, the things I changed:

1. Get the DOM element for the button with `document.getElementById()`
2. Use `addEventListener()` which is the standard way of adding event handlers
3. Change to the click event which is what buttons create when you click on them
4. Pass just a reference to the event handler as `BGcolor` without the parens.  You were calling it immediately rather than passing a reference to the function that can be called later.

In addition, a bunch of things to fix in your `BGcolor()` function:

1. Variables that remember their state from one function call to the next must be declared outside that function.
2. A color value is a string so you would use `"white"`, not `white`.
3. To change just the background color, it's best to use the `backgroundColor` property.

Here's a working version:

```
<button Id="BGchange">BUTTON!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("BGchange").addEventListener("click", BGcolor);

var curColor = "white";
function BGcolor (){
    if (curColor == "white") {
        curColor = "black";
    } else {
        curColor = "white";
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = curColor;
}
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Nk2N5/

Comment: Does this have to be an id which you assign an event handler to or can this be a tag name or class name?

Comment: @CodedContainer - You assign an event handler to a DOM element.  To do that, you have to get a reference to a DOM element.  There are lots of ways to do that.  Using an id with `document.getElementById()` is one such way to get a DOM element.  You could also use many other methods including class names, tag names, etc...  But, one advantage of an id is that is only one element with a given id so it's simpler to get a single DOM element by using an id.  One can assign a class name to many different DOM elements and obviously there can be many elements of a given tag type.

Comment: What happens if I append a new form group and want to use the same event listener? Would there be a reason this would not work?