# bind() in jquery 3.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I recently had to upgrade my JQuery version, one of my plugins stopped working as a result. I used the migrate plugin, I changed all the `bind()` to `on()`, but to no avail.

I use jQuery Parallax 1.1.3 by Ian Lunn ([found here](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/))

Inside of the called function there is the line

```
$window.bind('scroll', update).resize(update);
```

where update is a function. I changed this to

```
$window.on('scroll', update()).resize(update());
```

but `update()` isn't being called. `$window.scroll()` also isn't helping.

What can I do to restore functionality of my old functions?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - we do not know what `$window` or `update` is. It should be `$(window)` but we are guessing. Adding () certainly do not help unless the new update function returns a function

Comment: First adding `()`  after function name will call it immediately. Try `$window.on('scroll', update).resize(update)`. My guess is `update` function does not return anything so no function is being attached to event

Comment: Why have you changed `update` to `update()`? This way, this function is called immediatelly at the time of `on` calling and jQuery tries to bind `scroll` and `resize` events to the **result of `update` function execution**. Try `$window.on("scroll resize", update);`. It should work.

Comment: or even `$(window).on(...` in case $window is not what we think it is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event listener not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238722/event-listener-not-working)

Comment: I tried to make my question as compact as possible, my appologies if it wasn't clear enough. `$window` indeed refers to `$(window)`, the event also isn't working without the brackets. I can include the source of the plugin if you want, there is already a link. Upgrading to JQuery version 2 gives me no error, I was just wondering wat had changed in version 3.

Comment: Why not just ask him? http://www.twitter.com/IanLunn

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example with $window.scroll()

https://jsfiddle.net/sn7jr0ba/

```
function alertTemp(){
console.log("scrolled");
}
$( window ).scroll(alertTemp);
```

Comment: Don't alert an event that is triggered so often. Instead console.log it

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right direction for changing all `.bind()` to `.on()` for the newest jQuery, but you shouldn't use brackets in second parameter. Change this:

```
$window.on('scroll', update()).resize(update());
```

To this:

```
$window.on('scroll', update).resize(update);
```

It should work now. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The event also isn't working without the brackets, that was my first try. I can include the source of the plugin if you want, there is already a link. Upgrading to JQuery version 2 gives me no error, I was just wondering wat had changed in version 3.

Comment: You're welcome! The event handling with on is already correct, so if this still not work, maybe  the problem is in `$window` variable which pointing to element (I assume it refer to `$(window)` element), or what inside the `update()` function.

Comment: @ArneClicteur How about console.log? Any error message there? Maybe there's some clue.

Answer (score 0):

yes, remove the `()`,

Also you can group the events to make it more readable

```
$window.on('scroll resize', update);
```